# use dispatchEvent to dispatch it and wait until promise resolves

Tags: javascript

I have a custom build modal that has to stop executing any code after it when displayed. For me, this is not a problem when I call it directly (I can handle that) but the problem is when I have to use dispatchEvent on the related element. I've constructed the basic example here:

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = async function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    span.onclick = async function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      return await true;
    };
  });
};

(async () => {

  btn.style.color = "black";

  const event = new Event('click');
  await btn.dispatchEvent(event);
  
  btn.style.color = "red";
  
})();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}


.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal and wait (Note: this should't be red before closing modal)</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can **btn.dispatchEvent(event)** be awaited?

Comment: no, only Promise's can be awaited - `.dispatchEvent` returns a boolean (true || false) - also, your `span.onclick` makes no sense being `async` since the only thing it `await`s is a non-promise ... besides, the return value of an event handler isn't returned anywhere

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use `async` functions as DOM event listeners. The DOM does nothing with the promise that is returned. Also, avoid the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) -- `async` functions always return promises, you don't need to construct one.

Comment: Exactly when do you want the #myBtn to become red?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis after closing modal

Comment: Then you should put the btn.style.color = "red" line inside the span.onclick = function() handler. You can get rid of all the Promises and async/await statements.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis :)

Comment: Also, remember that you can use the addEventListener to run some code when an event has been dispatched: btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {}, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. It doesn't make any sense to use `async` functions as DOM event listeners. The DOM does nothing with the promise that is returned.
2. Avoid the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) — `async` functions always return promises, you don't need to construct one unless you need an explicit `resolve` or `reject` function.
3. You'll need to coordinate outside of the DOM event system, since `dispatchEvent` won't return the promise you're creating.

For instance, you can have a `modalPromise` and `modalResolve` that you set up initially like this:

```
let modalPromise = Promise.resolve();
let modalResolve = null;
```

...and then update like this when showing the modal:

```
modalPromise = modalPromise.then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        modalResolve = resolve;
    });
});
```

Then you `await` that after showing the modal.

Here's an idea (I've also updated it to use modern event handling, and to not use `var` — `var` has no place in modern JavaScript code):

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

let modalPromise = Promise.resolve();
let modalResolve = () => {};

span.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    if (modalResolve) {
        modalResolve();
        modalResolve = null;
    }
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalPromise = modalPromise.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            modalResolve = resolve;
        });
    });
});

(async () => {
    btn.style.color = "black";

    const event = new Event("click");
    btn.dispatchEvent(event);
    await modalPromise;

    btn.style.color = "red";
})();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}


.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal and wait (Note: this should't be red before closing modal)</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

That's just a sketch, you'll want to harden it against issues like trying to show the modal twice overlapping, etc.

Comment: this is something that I can use, of course, I will have to take care because in the chain of events many modals can be shown

Comment: can you explain to me how this works:     modalPromise = modalPromise.then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            modalResolve = resolve;
        });
    }); and the meaning of this call: modalResolve();, thanks

Comment: @DejanDozet - `modalResolve = resolve;` saves the `resolve` function from [the `Promise` executor call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#promise_terminology) to a variable you can use later to resolve (in this case, fulfill) the promise.

Comment: and I guess one function (modalPromise) is for one event handler to keep, but I have 3 buttons/click events on the modal so I will have to have 3 sets of modalPromise and modalResolve, isn't it?

Comment: @DejanDozet - `modalPromise` isn't a function, it's a promise. Yes, if those modals can be fired independently and can overlap, you'll need to repeat the pattern three times. I'd do it in a more structured way than a bunch of globals, but that's just a refinement.

Comment: sorry, modalPromise is a promise and modalResolve is a function

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities, the first one is - if you do not depend exactly on "dispatchEvent" - to use a possible replacer method, like this one:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

const openModal = () => {
  // This method will return a promise which we want to await,
  // until the modal is closed again. The promise awaiting for
  // close is called p.
  const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const onSpanClick = () => {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      span.removeEventListener('click', onSpanClick);
      resolve();
    };
  
    const onClick = () => {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      span.addEventListener('click', onSpanClick);
      btn.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    };

    btn.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  });

  // We need to return a double promise here, as we need to leave the function and return a promise to wait on, BEFORE the click is executed.
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    p.then(resolve);
    
    // otherwise we would return the promise after the click
    // was executed and our promise didn't had any chance to wait
    const event = new Event('click');
    btn.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
};

(async () => {
  btn.style.color = "black";
  await openModal();
  btn.style.color = "red";
})();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}


.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal and wait (Note: this should't be red before closing modal)</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

The other possiblity would be to do a hacky override of "btn.dispatchEvent" in order to assure that this behaviour is always guaranteed when "dispatchEvent" is called on the "btn"-instance, like this way:

```js
const oldDispatchEvent = btn.dispatchEvent.bind(btn);
btn.dispatchEvent = (event) => {
  // analyze event if it is a click event and create promise p (as in the
  //  "openModal" function in the snippet above (solution 1)
  
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
   p.then(resolve);
   oldDispatchEvent(event);
  });

  // else
  return oldDispatchEvent(event);
};
```

I personally wouldn't recommend the second solution as it is quiet dirty and non-standard, which means headaches, when you will have a view on your code in some months again. :D

Comment: hehe, I like that dirty solution better, but agree later when I forget that I've used it it could bring headaches, I like T.J. Crowder idea to keep the resolve function for later use because it is the closest that I have already, so will go with that approach, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simpler setup that will turn the text read, right after the modal is closed:

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
console.clear();

btn.onclick = async function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    btn.style.color = "red";
  };

};

(async () => {

  btn.style.color = "black";

  const event = new Event('click');
  btn.dispatchEvent(event);
  
})();
```

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
console.clear();

btn.onclick = async function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    btn.style.color = "red";
    return true;
  };

};

(async () => {

  btn.style.color = "black";

  const event = new Event('click');
  btn.dispatchEvent(event);
  
})();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}


.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal and wait (Note: this should't be red before closing modal)</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that I have chaining in my code, those are loops that are checking and unchecking checkboxes some checkboxes when checked (or unchecked) will yield a modal that the user has to accept (or reject) - code can't go forward because from that action it can go different ways. T.J. Crowder gave me a very good answer and from it, I learned something new, thanks

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear from the question and the code snippet. I understand the requirements clearly now, so an Event-based or Promise-based system might be the way to go.

Comment: I am using function call now instead using dispatchEvent, but dispatchEvent was the first idea that I got and I wondered if is it possible to use it with promises and that is why I asked this question. Now I learned that it is not possible + I learned that I can use promises as variables, and later use them in anywhere the code. This knowledge is important to me and helps me to understand better this cloudy topic.